# Implement Youtube Subscribe Button in Android

Tags: android, youtube

How can I implement youtube "subscribe button" for a channel in my android app.. I have searched [this site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) but couldn't find a solution for android apps..

Comment: Check this out https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert